# Windows SBS 2003 Remote Desktop Problem

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003

I used to remote access the SBS 2003 server through RDC and it has been working all the time but now I am unable to connect to the server.

Whenever I pressed the "Connect" button on the Remote Desktop Connection dialog, a dialog with messages like "Connecting to: xx.xx.xx.xx" and "Configuring remote session..." appeared and then disappeared quickly, leaving the Remote Desktop Connection dialog there.

How to fix the problem? Is the any way to reinstall the Remote Desktop on the server.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to reinstall RDP on the server or client site.

It seems that there is a configuration change in the open ports or if you use a certificate based authentication check your certificate if it's valid.